# How to store fresh figs

Tags: storage-method, fruit

How do I store fresh figs so that they stay good as long as possible?  I frequently experience that they get moldy within a few days after purchase, even when storing them in the refrigerator.  I wonder if there is anything that is more effective than simply storing them in the fridge in the basket I got them from the store in.

Comment: Have you tried [rinsing them in diluted vinegar](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/110759/85773) before storing them? This method is helpful in keeping strawberries from getting moldy, because it removes or kills mold spores on the surface.

Comment: @csk, I haven't, thank you, that is worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't that much more you can do. Fresh figs are perishable items, and before you get them you don't know how they've been stored. Moisture is your enemy here, the drier they stay the longer mold will stay at bay. The containers you buy them in often trap moisture so I would remove them from that packaging and store them in the refrigerator, on a shelf, uncovered.

Also, keep in mind that a bit of mold outside does not mean spoiled inside, I know it is unattractive but you can still cut them in half and scoop out the good stuff, provided that is still fresh enough.